# MVP Implementation - Solution/Project Structure

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvp

I am working on a WinForms game and before I get too deep into things, I would like to have some real structure and a good foundation to build off of. From what I've gathered, using an MVP pattern seems like the best way to go in my case. All of this is very new to me, so I have many questions, but the first that I would like to know the answer to is this:

In all of the MVP pattern examples I've found, the model is a single class. Should I need additional classes for custom objects and such, where would those be located within the structure of the pattern? I'm planning on making separate projects for each component of the pattern, so would my additional classes that relate to the model just go into my Model project?

I'm sort of confused about how to implement MVP on a larger-scale application. Everything I've found just uses MVP in very simple ways. Can anybody point me towards some sample code using MVP not on a grand scale by any means, but something a bit more complex than what is found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14660/WinForms-Model-View-Presenter

I would really appreciate any advice you would be willing to give me. Thanks!

Comment: `so would my additional classes that relate to the model just go into my Model project?` - yes, pretty much.

Comment: The game I'm working on is text-based and I am using windows forms because I honestly don't know what would be more appropriate for it. Obviously I'm looking for something a bit more presentable than a console app. What would you recommend?

Comment: If you care about clean code, design patterns and all that you may want to take a look at using WPF for the Presentation Layer and MVVM as a design pattern. It allows a true separation of UI and data/logic and helps create really interactive UIs with the least amout of boilerplate and dirty code. Plus, winforms is a dinosaur, and moving towards the XAML world will also help you introduce into the WinRT way of things

Comment: Wow, HighCore, you were absolutely right. WPF performs far better than WinForms and MVVM is a very nice pattern. You have just made my life a lot easier.

Comment: I'm glad you came to the Light Side.